# Difference between pointer to node and node as whole object?

Tags: c++, list, pointers, doubly-linked-list

If I have structure:
   /* Linked list structure */

```
struct list 
{
   struct list *prev;
   int data;
   struct list *next;
} ** *node = NULL, *first = NULL, *last = NULL, *node1 = NULL, *node2 = NULL**;

class linkedlist {
public: 

    /* Function for create/insert node at the beginning of Linked list */
    void insert_beginning() {
        **list *addBeg = new list;**
        cout << "Enter value for the node:" << endl;
        cin >> addBeg->data;
        if(first == NULL) {
            addBeg->prev = NULL;
            addBeg->next = NULL;
            first = addBeg;
            last = addBeg;
            cout << "Linked list Created!" << endl;
        }
        else {
            addBeg->prev = NULL;
            first->prev = addBeg;
            addBeg->next = first;
            first = addBeg;
            cout << "Data Inserted at the beginning of the Linked list!" << endl;
        }
    }
```

What is the SYNTAX difference between creating a new node (with 2 pointers and data) and just a single pointer apart from node, to use in same program. (Difference between bolded parts)

Comment: I can not understand what you are asking. Could you maybe include examples of **both** alternatives that you have in mind?

Comment: Google "so c++ book list".

Comment: What do you mean by syntax difference? You would have a pointer to the prev node and next node to be able to move forwards and backwards in your linked list or whatever data structure you have. It just depends on what you are designing

Comment: When you say "creating", do you mean on the stack (e.g. `int n;`) or on the heap (e.g. `int *p = new int;`)?

Comment: Are you talking about a doubly-linked list (prev, next) vs singly-linked list(next)?

Comment: for example: after I create structure, and i want to have instance of node(with pointers to previous and next node, and data), or if I just want to have a pointer itself, i dont know what is syntax difference between those two? may I have some example please

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples.

**Declaring a `node` variable**

```
node n;
```

Here `n` is a variable or instance of type `node`.

**Declaring a pointer to `node` type**

```
node * pointer_to_node;
```

Notice the `*` after the type identifier.  The `*` is used to declare pointers.

Also notice that the pointer is not pointing to anything.

**Pointing the Pointer**
A pointer can point to anything of its type.  So the following is valid:

```
node n;
node * pointer_to_node = &n;
```

In the above example, the `pointer_to_node` is initialized to *point to* the variable `n`.

```
node * pointer_to_dynamic = new node;
```

In the above statement, the program allocates a `node` instance in **dynamic** memory.  The location of the memory is assigned to the `pointer_to_dynamic` variable.  In other words, the variable `pointer_to_dynamic` now points to the newly allocated dynamic memory.